# WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 - JSON2XML policy not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, policy

There is `Hello World` API is onboarded into `WSO2 APIm 4.1.0 GA release`. I added `JSONtoXML` policy from `policy List` to Response flow by follows steps provided in [WSO2 APIM Doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-policies/attach-policy/) and deployed in DEV portal by clicking `save and deploy` option

**JsonToXML.j2 - Policy file Content:**

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
```

**Policy in publisher:**

[image: Policy in publisher]

When I Try out this API in DEV portal or via `postman`, it is still giving response as `JSON` format, not in `XML`

**WSO2 DEV Portal - TRY IT OUT:**

[image: WSO2 DEV Portal]

POSTMAN:

[image: postman]

**As suggested below - API Gateway Sequence Hit:**

[image: api gateway sequence test]

**CURL Request like below:**

```
curl -k "https://127.0.0.1:9443/api/am/gateway/v2/sequence?apiName=HelloWorld&version=1.0.0" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ4NXQiOiJOMkpqTWpOaU0xxx"
```

Note: valid token is passed in above curl Request, same token used when calling apim url which gives backend response

Did I miss anything or if not why this policy enablement is not working in WSO2 APIM? Please clarify on the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just followed the same flow to the Pizzashack API in the APIM 4.1.0 GA pack. It worked as expected without any issue. [image]

Can you confirm that you have created a new revision after this policy addition and deployed it in the gateway?

If you have done that as well, shall we use the [gateway Rest API](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/gateway-apis/gateway-v2/gateway-v2/#operation/getSequences) and check the sequences for the HelloAPI. There should be a new sequence with the above policy attached.

**Edit:**

If the sequence call does not contain a response, that means the policy has not been deployed properly. To apply the policy properly, create a new revision and deploy that revision in the gateway.

Comment: Hi @Lakshitha,
Yes deployed as new revision, As you suggested tested curl request via postman to check the sequence which gives 401 ERROR. curl -k "https://127.0.0.1:9443/api/am/gateway/v2/sequence?apiName=HelloWorld&version=1.0.0" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ4NXQiOiJOMkpqTWpOaU0xxx" Note: valid token passed in header section and the same token is used when calling apim url. Added image in question

Comment: Use basic auth with admin credentials for this API request. Default "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="

Comment: Hi @Lakshitha,
Thanks for suggestion, after using basic Auth, sequence is empty, got below Response. {
    "sequences": []
}

Comment: This means the policy has not been applied. Shall we create another revision and deploy? Let's check the sequence after that as well. Also please verify that the policy is already applied to the correct resource and the API is saved.

Comment: @Justin I have updated the answer with these steps.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by @Lakshitha, i followed below STEPS and working as expected.

- Restarted WSO2 APIm standalone server
- Added policy in `GET` resourse of HelloWorld API
- Deployed as `new Revision`
- In DEV Portal, API tested via `TRY OUT` option and got `XML` response now
  [image: DEV Postal Response]

Gateway API also given sequence response like BELOW

[image: Gateway sequence API]